# How do I know that I'm still on the correct page when an async callback returns?

Tags: microsoft-metro, winjs

I'm building a Metro app using the [single-page navigation model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452768.aspx). On one of my pages I start an async ajax request that fetches some information. When the request returns I want to insert the received information into the displayed page.

For example:

```
WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/showstuff.html", {
    processed: function (element, options) {
        WinJS.xhr(...).done(function (result) {
            element.querySelector('#target').innerText = result.responseText;
        });
    }
};
```

But how do I know that the user hasn't navigated away from the page in the meantime? It doesn't make sense to try to insert the text on a different page, so how can I make sure that the page that was loading when the request started is still active?

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the pages URI with the current `WinJS.Navigation.location` to check if you are still on the page. You can use `Windows.Foundation.Uri` to pull the path from the pages URI to do this.

```
WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/showstuff.html", {
    processed: function (element, options) {
        var page = this;

        WinJS.xhr(...).done(function (result) {
            if (new Windows.Foundation.Uri(page.uri).path !== WinJS.Navigation.location)
                return;

            element.querySelector('#target').innerText = result.responseText;
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an official way to do this, so I implemented a workaround.

[`WinJS.Navigation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229778.aspx) provides events that are fired on navigation. I used the [`navigating` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229843.aspx) to build a simple class that keeps track of page views:

```
var PageViewManager = WinJS.Class.define(
    function () {
        this.current = 0;
        WinJS.Navigation.addEventListener('navigating',
                this._handleNavigating.bind(this));
    }, {
        _handleNavigating: function (eventInfo) {
            this.current++;
        }
    });

Application.pageViews = new PageViewManager();
```

The class increments a counter each time the user starts a new navigation.

With that counter, the Ajax request can check if any navigation occurred and react accordingly:

```
WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/showstuff.html", {
    processed: function (element, options) {
        var pageview = Application.pageViews.current;

        WinJS.xhr(...).done(function (result) {
            if (Application.pageViews.current != pageview)
                return;

            element.querySelector('#target').innerText = result.responseText;
        });
    }
};
```